# Implement a dropdown history in a UITextField or similar component

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, storyboard

I have a case where users enter a string, and would like the users to be able to quickly select the previously entered, and validated options they have entered before.

Currently the user enters text via a UITextField, ideally I'd like to keep this, or aesthetically this at least, and have a list of the previously validated inputs drop down below, where tapping any of them would fill the UITextView.

Basically I want a dropbox, which is simply filled with previous inputs, but those inputs are not listed on the main UI, only when the user selects the text view.

Can anyone point me towards how to acomplish this?

Comment: use NSUserDefault to save users previously enter value

Comment: Thanks, should have mentioned that the saving part is not the stumbling block, its the how to display this data as the dropdown type list from the textfield.